# How to stream sounds from local computer on my index.html which is hosted on a web server

Tags: html

I was wondering if i can stream my pc's sounds to my server html file.
Is it possible?
Till now i only have found a program called Stream "What You Hear"
that stream the sound only localy.
http://192.168.1.4:80/stream/swyh.mp3
Thank you for your time..

Answer (score 0):

download Stream What You Hear
Get the Http Live streaming address like this one
 http://192.168.1.4:80/stream/swyh.mp3

download ngrok.exe
create a batch file START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\Users\username\ & ngrok.exe http 80"
run the batch and cmd will open with the tunel like this one
http ://xxx.ngrok.io

go to a computer outside your network
and go to page http ://xxx.ngrok.io/stream/swyh.mp3

So now you can stream for free